# how to convert a msvc exe project to a dll project?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, exe

in the exe project:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( __in HINSTANCE hInstance, __in_opt HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, __in_opt LPSTR lpCmdLine, __in int nShowCmd )
{
    g_hMainWnd=CreateDialog(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),NULL,(DLGPROC)DialogProc);
    RECT rcWnd;
    GetWindowRect(g_hMainWnd,&rcWnd);
    int X=(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)-rcWnd.right+rcWnd.left)>>1,
        Y=(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-rcWnd.bottom+rcWnd.top)>>1;
    MoveWindow(g_hMainWnd,X,Y,rcWnd.right-rcWnd.left,rcWnd.bottom-rcWnd.top,FALSE);
    ShowWindow(g_hMainWnd,SW_SHOW);

    BOOL bRet;
    MSG msg;
    while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
    { 
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,_T("GetMessage error with -1 returned！"),_T("error"),MB_ICONHAND);
            break;
        }
        else if (!IsWindow(g_hMainWnd) || !IsDialogMessage(g_hMainWnd, &msg)) 
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I changed the project setting to output a dll firstly.
Then I changed the WinMain to:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( __in HINSTANCE hInstance, __in_opt HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, __in_opt LPSTR lpCmdLine, __in int nShowCmd )
{

    g_hMainWnd=CreateDialog(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),NULL,(DLGPROC)DialogProc);
    HWND hMainWnd;
   //DialogProc involves the critical initialization of the data required for the export function used later


    return 0;
}
```

So, if it is a foolish idea, or have I missed something?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
   BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpReserved )  // reserved
{
    // Perform actions based on the reason for calling.
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         // Initialize once for each new process.
         // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         // Do thread-specific initialization.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         // Do thread-specific cleanup.
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         // Perform any necessary cleanup.
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.
}
```

For more informations: [Dll entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of DllMain is to be used by the operating system, and on a few occasions you must enter their codes. To execute the code that implements your EXE, you must create a public routine that receives the required parameters.

Use Visual Studio do create one library project to export some data and functions. 
New Project**->** Select Viasual c++ **->** Select Win32 **->** Win32 Project **->** Name your project **->** Next **->** Select DLL **->** Select Export symbols **->** finish

The final project will contain a variable being exported and a public routine. Use as a template in your code.